# How do I handle different logic when user tap of push notification banner either from background or foreground?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have this to handle push notification:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    save(userInfo)
    // Do something with userInfo based on whether we tapped the push notif whe the app is opened or in the background

    completionHandler()
}
```

Now what I want to do is to implement a logic that will be quite different between when the push notification is tapped when the app is openend (foreground) or when it is hidden (background). How do I differentiate between those two? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is look at the `applicationState` property of `UIApplication`.

```swift
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    save(userInfo)

    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
        // App in foreground when user tapped notification
    } else {
        // App in background when user tapped notification
    }

    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much. I was thinking it was in the UNNotificationResponse but I couldn't find it. Why didn't I think about checking the UIApplication singleton. Thanks again.